# Firefox caching my extension. How to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I simply want to include jQuery and then my custom JS file to call ready() event. For testing I put an alert on my .js file, it worked fine. Now when I change content of my js file it keeps giving same old alert. In console now it shows:

> Could not read chrome manifest
>   'file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/extensions/%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D/chrome.manifest'.

Why is it so hard to call JS files, specially jquery functions?

My files content given below:

**chrome.manifest**

```
content myext content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myext /content/myext.xul
```

**myext.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="Scrapper-Overlay"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://fbpicker/content/functions.js" />
</overlay>
```

**functions.js**

Initially I put **alert('test');** it popped up. Later I put:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
    {
        alert("addd");
    }, false);
}, false);
```

But it is keep showing *test* as popup.

Why FF is caching the content and how to remove it?

On Console  I am getting following warnings:

```
Timestamp: 8/6/2013 2:15:32 PM
Warning: XUL box for _moz_generated_content_before element contained an inline #text child, forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block.
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/toolbar.xml
Line: 382

Timestamp: 8/6/2013 2:15:32 PM
Warning: XUL box for _moz_generated_content_before element contained an inline #text child, forcing all its children to be wrapped in a block.
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml
Line: 0

Timestamp: 8/6/2013 2:15:34 PM
Warning: Key event not available on some keyboard layouts: key="b" modifiers="accel,alt"
Source File: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
Line: 0


Timestamp: 8/6/2013 2:15:30 PM
Warning: Unknown property 'order'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: resource://gre-resources/ua.css
Line: 46
```

Answer (score 3):

See the ["Setting up an extension development environment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) article on MDN, in particular the bits about `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache`. Also, the `Firefox extension proxy file` is very useful.

While the page talks about Firefox a lot, most of the content also applies to other mozilla-powered apps, such as Thunderbird, Seamonkey or InstantBird.

JFYI: Using jquery in extensions, in particular XUL overlay based ones, while somewhat discouraged, is OK, as long as you preferably [load it as a subscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIJSSubScriptLoader), or at least `.noConflict()` it. This is because overlays share the same scope/namespace. See [JavaScript Object Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/JavaScript_Object_Management) from the XUL School tutorial for more information.

Comment: I am already using proxy file but I need to enable/disable all the time to see changes. I have to try other bit you just mentined.

Comment: the following entry does not exist in firefox 19

Comment: I am unable to figure out. There is a DIV on the visited page with ID *blueBar*, either I do jQuery way _$("#blueBar").html()_ or _aEvent.originalTarget.getElementById.innerHTML("blueBar")_ both gives **undefined** error.

Comment: You need to create the pref yourself. And regarding jquery: Make sure you operate on the correct window/document objects. The main window/document are browser.xul and the actual browser windows are contained within it as sub-documents. Again, see MDN.

Comment: PS: Your code will of course only reload when you open a new window, and then only in that window, and only if you have the xul cache disabled. Enabling/Disabling add-ons in a session does not work unless it is a correctly implemented restartless add-on (which cannot use such overlays to begin with).

Comment: I did what you are saying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083629/firefox-extension-how-to-access-page-element-via-jquery

Comment: There's an extension developer extension that lets you toggle/untoggle debugging prefs.