# FireFox extension: How to access page element via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I am using following code:

```
   var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
        if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
        var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
        //alert("page is loaded \n" +doc.location.href);
       // alert(doc.location.href.indexOf("facebook.com"));
        if(doc.location.href.indexOf("facebook.com") == -1) 
        {
            return;
        }
        alert("we are here");
        alert($("#blueBar").html());
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);
```

It keeps giving `undefined` error

Comment: Can you be more specific on this error?  Does it mention the variable or function that is undefined?

Comment: when I alert _$('#bluebar')_ it gives **[object]** but when I call it's _html()_ method it says undefined.

Comment: And facebook always has an element with id=blueBar that is fully loaded before `onPageLoad` triggers?  Try looking at the element through a developer tool (like firebug) to make sure it exists.  If so the element may be loaded after the page.

Comment: _And facebook always has an element with id=blueBar that is fully loaded before onPageLoad _  How would I know it? I assume onPageLoad calls once all element are loaded. I have to use this element, I found no issue to access them in Chrome and IE version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` will use the document of the current window by default. Which is actually browser.xul in your case. You need to operate on the sub-document, which you already got via `var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;`, so this should work I think (untested)

```
$(doc).find("#blueBar")
```

Comment: Are you sayin that I can't use $(#myelemt) thing in extension and I will have to _find_ them first and then use them?

Comment: Ok seems it's working now. I did this: *$(doc).find("#blueBar").html()* . On first call it goes undefined and then it loads innerHTML.

Comment: In practise yes (or was there a way to re-bind jquery?). You can still use $("#id") to look for stuff within browser.xul, but not in sub-documents, an all tabs, or more specifically the pages displayed in tabs, are sub-documents. Also, did I mention that using jquery in XUL overlay add-ons is discouraged?

Comment: Thinking about it, you may be better off with the add-on sdk and page-mods, which makes it easy to run code on a page load and use jquery with that page. https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/builder and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html

Comment: will document.getElement will work for sub-documents automatically?

Comment: Not like you think. Remember `document` is browser.xul! Still assuming `var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;` what will work is `doc.getElement*` and `doc.querySelector*` and `doc.evaluate` and so on.

Comment: I find a bit learning curve in new model of extensions and I don' have much time. I tried to fiddle with Addon Builder but due to lack of _CommonJS_ knowledge I could not go thru

Comment: Thanks Bro! Finally I able to make it. I have reasons to use jQuery for this particular task to keep code sync across all browsers.

Comment: you were right, jquery was not going good for me, I used traditional JS. One thing. I injected HTML of a popup Div having an onclick event calling a function **closepop()** which I defined in my .js file referred in XUL. Now How do I call that function from Injected dIV?